# Realtime conversions not showing destination funnel

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, goal-tracking, single-page-application

I'm trying to make my **custom destination funnel** work.

Here's how it's set up:

[image]

I confirm the individual steps are being recorded in the Content page:

[image]

However, when I finish the flow, I don't see the funnel goal being recorded in the Conversions page:

[image]

What's going on here?

Comment: Can you confirm you're seeing `/welcome-candidate/success` hits specifically? The funnel is not considered when GA determines whether a goal conversion has taken place or not.

Comment: @Reve yup, just tested it. I the string completely matches what's in the Destination: "/welcome-candidate/success"

Comment: @Reve btw, what do you mean "The funnel is not considered when GA determines whether a goal conversion has taken place or not"? The funnel is not considered what exactly?

Comment: "not considered" meaning "ignored". Whether a goal conversion is counted or not depends only on the final destination being reached - the funnel definition affects only one report, Conversions > Goals > Funnel Visualization. Which is still useful - that is a very informative report - but a significant limitation.

Comment: One more comment, because the edit pencil isn't doing anything and it will bother me if I leave it: two reports. The funnel shows up in Goal Flow as well as Funnel Visualization.

Answer (score 1):

Well, from your screenshots, I can't say for sure, but here are Things To Check:

**The exact match is exact:** no query parameters or ending slash on the visited page, no trailing spaces in the goal definition. You could see whether changing the match type from "Equals To" to "Regular Expression" fixes the problem. Unless you have another page that contains the string `/welcome-candidate/success` and *shouldn't* count as a goal completion, regex should be fine to use for the goal definition.

**The goal is active:** definition saved, and Recording set to On. Recording may turn on automatically when you save, but I don't remember for sure and would double-check it.

Other things I think about but probably aren't the problem, included for completeness:

I usually switch to the Last 30 Minutes display in Real-Time, because it shows more information than the Active Users display, but if you're checking immediately after visiting `/welcome-candidate/success` that shouldn't matter.

Filtering out one's own traffic can be an issue with this sort of data, but if that were the case you would also not see the pageviews showing up.

Comment: I agree with @Reve regarding is the goal active? Unless the last screenshot cut it off the bottom, it seems to indicate the goal isn't set to active (or maybe added to a different view?). If it were active, it would be listed in the Goal column in the Real Time > Conversion report with the other two listed (kromid & Forgot Password Funnel). Also keep in mind, if testing a goal, clear cookies each time or use a new incognito window each time. this will end the current session so as further tests will register a goal if they occur (can only register as a goal once during the same session)